# 1000000000000000000 на входе с типом int в mysql превращается в 2147483647. Почему?

Tags: mysql, python, django

Не пойму почему выводится не понятная строка. Объясните что не так, на локальном сервере все показывается нормально но когда я залил проект на хостинг nginx+mysql (на локалке стоял тестовый сервер и sqlite) началась такая лабуда:

```
@register.filter
def eth(value):
"""Removes all values of arg from the given string"""
return str(int(value)/1000000000000000000)+" ETH"
```

функция фильтр, которой на вход попадает цифровое значение 1000000000000000000 это единица с 18 нулями, что бы перевести это значение в eth(эфириум) мы делим это цифру на 1000000000000000000 потому что в 1 эфире 18 нулей, должна получиться единица а получается вот такое чудо

> 2.147483647e-09 ETH

в базе данных  тип поля стоит int не могу разобраться в чем дело, еще раз повторюсь на локальном тестовом сервере джанги все работает корректно. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Python на обоих серверах одной версии?

Comment: на сервере 3.5 на локалке 3.6

Comment: А числа какого порядка нужно хранить в БД? Возможно поля с типом int не хватает.

Comment: ну целые числа с 18 нулями и того максимум 19 знаков

Comment: Ну явно БД по умолчанию такие длинные числа не хранит. Храните лучше их в VARCHAR, есть ещё интересный тип `DECIMAL`: с указанием количества хранимых знаков до и после точки - лучшее решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гугл говорит, что в MySQL тип INT вмещает числа до 4294967295. То есть явно сюда не влезет "целое число с 18 нулями". Не очень понятно, почему БД у вас не выбрасывает ошибку, если вы всё-таки пытаетесь хранить там такие числа, но, рекомендую вам взять BIGINT UNSIGNED - его должно вполне хватить.

Comment: «почему БД у вас не выбрасывает ошибку» — потому что MySQL по умолчанию замалчивает большинство ошибок

Comment: диапазон у int `-2**31`, `2**31-1` то есть до `2147483647`

Comment: @jfs, если рассматривать только SIGNED версию инта, то всё верно. Но у UNSIGNED верхний предел будет вдвое выше.

Comment: какой по вашему тип получится если просто INT указать?

Comment: Все верно оно даже не все цифры записало в бд, интересно почему sqlite нормально все пропустило. Я сделал дамп с sqlite и потом с помощью loaddata залил в mysql и получается туда попали не все цифры, но как не странно ошибок не было. Вообщем переделал, сделал полю тип varchar и все работает. Спасибо за помощь!